# strange creases in my model

Tags: rendering, lighting, unreal-engine

how do i get rid of this crease on my model's hip? help greatly appreciated.
the creases dont appear in cycles rendered or look dev, but they do appear in solid mode, and when i exported it to ue4, the shading was really wrong.[image: MatCap]

[image: look Dev[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juJIZ.png)

Comment: May be wrong face directons. Try to recalculate the normals outside. It's in the mesh menu in edit mode or Ctrl+n. (Select everything)

Comment: it's hard to say what you're talking about, maybe share the part of your file where you see your problem?